# Stuck trying to solve this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{3y}{(3y^{2/3}-x)}$$

So I wrote this as: 
$$\dfrac{dx}{dy}= \dfrac{(3y^{2/3}-x)}{3y}$$ 
$$\therefore \dfrac{dx}{dy} + \dfrac{x}{3y} = y^{-1/3}$$

If I let $v=y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ then:

$$\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \frac{2}{3}y^{-1/3}\dfrac{dx}{dv}$$
$$\therefore \dfrac{dx}{dv}+\dfrac{x}{2}y^{-2/3} = \dfrac{9}{2}$$

But when I try to solve this by multiplying through by an integrating factor I get stuck. So I was wondering if this method is a correct way to solve this equation?

Comment: Try writing $v=\frac{x}{y}$, such that $x'=v'y+y'v$, and then, you'll get rid of x and end up with a linear equation $v'=-\frac{1}{3}v+y^{-\frac{1}{3}}$

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M(x, y)  =  3 y$ and $N(x, y)  =  x-3 y^{2/3}$ so that the equation is $M+Ny'=0$

This is not an exact equation, because $M_y(x, y)=  3 \neq 1  =  N_x(x, y)$.

We have to find an integrating factor $\mu(y)$ such that $\mu(y) M(x, y)+\mu(y)N(x, y)y' = 0$ is exact.
This means $\frac{\partial \mu M}{\partial y} =  \frac{\partial \mu N}{\partial x} $ that is
$$3 y \mu'+3 \mu  =  \mu$$
Isolating $\mu(y)$
$$\frac{\mu'}{\mu}  =  -\frac{2}{3 y}$$
and integrating both sides with respect to $y$ we find
$$\mu(y)  =  y^{-2/3}.$$
Multiplying both sides of the original ODE $3 y+(x-3 y^{2/3}) y'= 0$ by $\mu$ we have
$$3 y^{1/3}+\left(\frac{x}{y^{2/3}}-3\right)y' =  0.$$
Let $P(x, y)  =  3 y^{1/3}$ and $Q(x, y)  = \frac{x}{y^{2/3}}-3$ so that $P+Qy'=0$. This is an exact equation, because $P_y  =  y^{-2/3}  =  Q_x$.

Defining $f(x, y)$ such that $f_x(x, y)= P(x, y)$ and $f_y(x, y)  =  Q(x, y)$, the solution will be given by $f(x, y)  =  K$, where $K$ is an arbitrary constant.
Integrate $f_x(x, y)$ with respect to $x$ in order to find $f(x, y)$
$$
f(x, y)  =   \int 3 y^{1/3} \operatorname{d}x  =  3 y^{1/3} x+g(y)
$$ 
where $g(y)$ is an arbitrary function of $y$.

Differentiating $f(x, y)$ with respect to $y$ in order to find $g(y)$
$$
\frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial y}  =  \frac{x}{y^{2/3}}+g'(y)
$$
and substituting into $f_y(x, y)=  Q(x, y)$ we find
$$\frac{x}{y^{2/3}}+g'(y)  =  \frac{x}{y^{2/3}}-3$$
and finally
$$g(y)  =   \int-3 \operatorname{d}y  =  -3 y.$$
Substituting $g(y)$ into $f(x, y)$ we have
$f(x, y)  =  3 y^{1/3} x-3 y$ and then the solution is
$$ 3 y^{1/3} x-3 y  =  K$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{\totald{y}{x} = {3y \over 3y^{2/3}-x}.\quad}$ Let $x = \alpha\,\tilde{x}$ and
$y = \beta\,\tilde{y}$. Then,

> $$
> {\beta \over \alpha}\,\totald{\tilde{y}}{\tilde{x}}
> =
> {3\beta\tilde{y} \over 3\beta^{2/3}\tilde{y}^{2/3} - \alpha\tilde{x}}
> \quad\imp\quad
> \totald{\tilde{y}}{\tilde{x}}
> =
> {3\tilde{y} \over 3\pars{\beta^{2/3}/\alpha}\tilde{y}^{2/3} - \tilde{x}}
> $$
> The equation has the same form whenever $\beta^{2/3}/\alpha = 1$ which is equivalent to
> $$
> \pars{y \over \tilde{y}}^{2/3} = {x \over \tilde{x}}\quad\imp\quad
> {y^{2/3} \over x} = {\tilde{y}^{2/3} \over \tilde{x}^{2/3}}
> $$
> It suggests the change $u = y^{2/3}/x\quad\imp\quad y=x^{3/2}u^{3/2}$
> $$
> {3 \over 2}x^{1/2}u^{3/2} + x^{3/2}\pars{{3 \over 2}\,u^{1/2}u'}
> =
> {3x^{3/2}u^{3/2} \over 3xu - x} 
> $$

$$
x^{-1}u + u'
=
{2u \over 3xu - x}\quad\imp\quad
u' = {2u \over \pars{3u - 1}x} - {u \over x}
=
{2u - u\pars{3u - 1} \over \pars{3u - 1}x}
=
{-3u^{2} + 3u \over \pars{3u - 1}x}
$$

> \begin{align}
> &x + \overbrace{C}^{\mbox{constant}}
> =
> -\int{u - 1/3 \over u\pars{u - 1}}\,\dd u
> =
> -\int\pars{u - {1 \over 3}}\pars{{1 \over u - 1} - {1 \over u}}\,\dd u
> \\[3mm]&=
> -\int\pars{1 + {2/3 \over u - 1} - 1 + {1/3 \over u}}\,\dd u
> =
> -\bracks{{2 \over 3}\,\ln\pars{u - 1} + {1 \over 3}\,\ln\pars{u}}
> =
> -\ln\pars{\bracks{u - 1}^{2/3}u^{1/3}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\pars{u - 1}^{2}u = \expo{-3\pars{x + C}} = A\expo{-3x}
\quad\mbox{where}\ A\ \mbox{is a constant and}\ y = \pars{xu}^{3/2}}
$$